# MySQL | PHP - Gather rows by two different date

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table like this (where 'date' is when the user ask for a validation and 'date_validation' is when it's validated:

```
id | type | date | date_validation | equipement_id
```

I can sort it by date or rather date_validation by a simple sorting and by doing some PHP code.

### Display I have

**12/06/17**

*ID '1', Ask for validation*

*ID '2', Ask for validation*

**12/06/17**

*ID '3', validated*

**10/06/17**

*ID '4', Ask for validation*

**10/06/17**

*ID '5', validated*

### Display I would like to have

**12/06/17**

*ID 1', Ask for validation*

*ID '2', Ask for validation*

*ID '3', validated*

**10/06/17**

*ID '4', Ask for validation*

*ID 5', validated*

---

How to gather informations by date, while having two different date column?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How to gather informations by date, while having two different date column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
SELECT id,  date as dt, 'Ask for validation' AS DtTtype
FROM thetable
UNION ALL
SELECT id,  date_validation  as dt, 'validated' AS DtType
FROM thetable
ORDER BY dt
```

In the PHP, break on the `dt` field, and the `dttype` field  give you what type of date it is

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it solved my problem! Thank you!